# What is the purpose of Reviewing after reaching Steward?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-queues

Many of us might have come across this stage where we have reviewed 1000 questions and answers and gained the Steward gold badge.

Already after passing the 2000 reputation limit, we already noticed that we are no longer promoted by receiving a +2 reputation award on every successful review. So after reaching the 1000 review cap, there seems to be no more to gain from reviews.

By then we would have understood the lesson that the purpose for reviewing is not to gain any badges or reputation, but to help the SO community and its users to have better Q & A.

So my question/proposition is: Can something be done for those users who have reached the 1000 reviews and would like to continue contributing while gaining something back from their contribution given.

An example could be that the +2 reputation for each successfully accepted review be re-introduced for these kind of users.

Comment: are you confusing between suggested edit and review? For review, you get no +s.

Comment: So, you realize reviewing is for the common good, not to gain any badge, but you still want an incentive? Why?

Comment: Giving back doesn't require *payment*.

Comment: *By your standard then just remove the Steward and Reviewer badges.* Oh, how I would love that, if only to get rid of the review drones once and for all. Alas, that doesn't seem to be happening.

Comment: What is the purpose of Reviewing if it's only for reaching Steward?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I'd want the Reviewer and Steward badges retroactively removed, too. And yes, I'd lose a number of them myself  - and I'd be perfectly fine with that, if it delivered us from the robo reviewer plague!

Comment: I disagree with this proposal (voting down), because it would make the robo-reviewing problem even worse. If people get 2 points for things after gaining Steward, even more people will robo-review their way towards the Steward badge.

Comment: then @S.L.Barth my proposition would be to remove the Steward badge completely as it does not have any sense at all.

Comment: @codedByMi That seems quite the opposite of what your question says. If I understand your comments right, you have _two_ proposals. (1) Keep rewarding reviewers and (2) Do not reward reviewers at all. Although I think neither proposal will be popular.

Comment: There is a pretty simple purpose beyond getting a badge or a spot on a leaderboard: To make the site better in general.

Comment: Frankly, you should not have received that badge in the first place: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10973313 http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10766003 http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10849443 http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10355479 http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10328869. I don't often say this, but please never use the review queues again.

Comment: @BradLarson Did you remove all review badges from him? o_O?

Comment: @Magisch - Oh, I wish I could. Although if having the badge is enough to get certain reviewers to stop, maybe taking those away would do more damage as they attempt to game the system again.

Comment: @BradLarson I was asking because I looked and OP has almost no review badges. Only one steward.

Comment: @BradLarson - Were those *real* suggested edits or just something done to create an audit?

Comment: My intention is purely to credit well done reviews and not to have any badges. In fact I only have one review gold badge. And I'm not looking to receive anymore any time soon.

Comment: @BSMP No, they're just audits. Randomly generated nonsense. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171204/are-the-suggested-edit-audits-too-easy

Comment: Thought you'd like to know this... [Visual design changes to the review queues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/360198/364217): "There is more incentive to continue reviewing. The Steward badge can now be earned multiple times for every 1,000 reviews in each queue. If you have already completed 2,000 or more reviews, we will backfill any additional Steward badges that you have already earned. You can expect to see them accrue over the next few days."

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The goal of the review queues is not to improve *your* reputation. It is to improve the *community's* quality and content.

As a "thank you" for helping to improve the quality of the site, you are granted a couple badges. If you want more than that, and do not care about the quality of the site, please take a step back from the queues. Thank you for your help so far, but you should find another area of the site to assist with at this point.

If, on the other hand, you want to continue to improve the quality of the site, then continue doing the reviews. You'll find that you can still improve a number next to your name:

- [Top Close Reviewers](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/stats)
- [Top Triage Reviewers](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/stats)
- [Top Reopen Reviewers](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/stats)
- [Top Suggested Edit Reviewers](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/stats)
- [Top Help and Improvement Reviewers](https://stackoverflow.com/review/helper/stats)
- [Top First Post Reviewers](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/stats)
- [Top Late Answer Reviewers](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/stats)
- [Top Low Quality Reviewers](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/stats)